# What are the issues with preallocating objects in Java?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

We've spent the last few months tuning our production application so that we experience no full GCs. We now experience young GCs only, with the rate of young GCs dependent on the rate of object allocation.

Our application needs to be as close to "real-time" as possible so now we're trying to reduce the number of young GCs. As the old axiom goes, most of the data we allocate ends up being garbage and discarded at the next young GC. So no need to preallocate for this type of data. However there is a good amount of objects (defined by type) that we know will make it from young GC to old GC.

Would it make sense to preallocate these objects during more ideal times (i.e. at startup) so we'll end up allocating less during our less-than-ideal times? I've read the literature that mentions how object pooling is not recommended with the latest JVMs because allocation is much cheaper. What are the drawbacks to preallocating objects that I know will make it to the old GC?

Comment: I don't know how anyone can help you with that, as the answer is most likely very, very dependent on your concrete code and the platform you run on. Benchmark it and you will see.

Comment: Not to be trollish, but if you're that worried about memory management, shouldn't you code the darned thing in c++?

Comment: or use a JVM specially designed for real-time

Answer (score 3):

Reducing the rate of allocation makes GC "pauses" less frequent, but not shorter. For smoother "real-time" operation, you may actually want to *increase* the number of GC invocations: this is trading more GC-related CPU in order to get shorter pauses. Sun's JVM can be tuned with various [options](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp); I suggest trying `-XX:NewRatio` to make the young generation smaller.

The usual argument against pooling is that you are basically trying to write your own allocator, hoping that you will do a better job at it than the JVM allocator. It is justified in some specific cases where allocation is expensive, e.g. creating `Thread` instances.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note that there is a [realtime jvm](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp) available.  If your app needs predictable performance then this is a worth looking into.